# Need to get/display properties from a variable

Tags: javascript

I have searched but perhaps just don't understand and need an actual person to help explain. I have a script that generates the following variable:

```
var trackerResult = {
    "sessionId": "16zA06FJt5sp",
    "customerId": "16zA06FJt5so",
    "contact": {
        "firstName": "Bilbo",
        "lastName": "Baggins",
        "email": "bbshireguy@gmail.com"
    },
    "orders": [{
        "orderId": "16zA06FJt5ss",
        "number": 11512,
        "items": [{
            "price": 97,
            "productId": "16zA06FJt3of",
            "productName": "Main"
        }]
    }, {
        "orderId": "16zA06FJt5sw",
        "number": 11513,
        "items": [{
            "price": 49,
            "productId": "16zA06FJt3op",
            "productName": "Upsell"
        }]
    }],
    "demoMode": "1"
};
```

I need to be able to simply display the productName and the price. If what the script generated were a bit more simple I could do it, but as I understand what I am looking at there is properties that are technically a child of a child?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.digital-web.com/articles/objectifying_javascript/

Comment: trackerResult.orders[0].items[0].price  trackerResult.orders[0].items[0].productName  You can iterater them with `forEach`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2098276/102937

Answer (score 3):

```
trackerResult.orders.forEach( function ( order ) {
    order.items.forEach( function ( item ) {
        console.log( item.productName, item.price );
    });
});
```

(`forEach` is not implemented in IE8/7, so you'll want to [shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) it for those browsers)

Answer (score 0):

First, take that object and add some whitespace so you can actually see what's going on:

```
var trackerResult = {
    "sessionId":"16zA06FJt5sp",
    "customerId":"16zA06FJt5so",
    "contact":{
        "firstName":"Bilbo",
        "lastName":"Baggins",
        "email":"bbshireguy@gmail.com"
    },
    "orders":[
        {
            "orderId":"16zA06FJt5ss",
            "number":11512,
            "items":[
                {
                    "price":97,
                    "productId":"16zA06FJt3of",
                    "productName":"Main"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "orderId":"16zA06FJt5sw",
            "number":11513,
            "items":[
                {
                    "price":49,
                    "productId":"16zA06FJt3op",
                    "productName":"Upsell"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "demoMode":"1"
};
```

Now, to get the product name and price, you might do something like:

```
var orders = trackerResult.orders,
    ordercnt = orders.length,
    items, itemcnt, i, j,
    output = "";
for( i=0; i<ordercnt; i++) {
    output += "Order #"+orders[i].number+"\n==========\n";
    items = orders[i].items;
    itemcnt = items.length;
    for( j=0; j<itemcnt; j++) output += items[j].productName+" "+items[j].price;
    output += "\n";
}
// do something with "output";
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're missing a colon ':' after `"contact"`.

Now, inside the `trackerResult` variable the field that interests you is the `orders` array. In each member of the `orders` array, there is a `items` array. Every item contains the name and price.

So we'll just traverse these two fields in two nested cycles.

```
var trackerResult = {"sessionId":"16zA06FJt5sp","customerId":"16zA06FJt5so","contact": {"firstName":"Bilbo","lastName":"Baggins","email":"bbshireguy@gmail.com"},"orders":[{"orderId":"16zA06FJt5ss","number":11512,"items":[{"price":97,"productId":"16zA06FJt3of","productName":"Main"}]},{"orderId":"16zA06FJt5sw","number":11513,"items":[{"price":49,"productId":"16zA06FJt3op","productName":"Upsell"}]}],"demoMode":"1"};

var result = '';

for (var i = 0; i < trackerResult.orders.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < trackerResult.orders[i].items.length; j++) {
        result += trackerResult.orders[i].items[j].productName + ': ' +  trackerResult.orders[i].items[j].price + '\n';
    }
}

alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is an error in the var - it is missing a `:` after `"contact"`. Fixing this will allow us to continue :)

Then, once that is set, you need to iterate over your orders to see get all the products and their prices.

```
for ( var i = 0, l = trackerResult.orders.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    var order = trackerResult.orders[i];
    for ( var j = 0, k = order.items.length; j < k; j++ ) {
        var item = order.items[j];

        // here are the values you need to do something with
        // so do something with them now!
        var productName = item.productName;
        var price = item.price;
        console.log( productName, price );
    }
}
```

Not sure what you are trying to do with the products, but this will get you access to them!

Answer (score 0):

To access, say a order item you would use:

```
trackerResult.orders[1].items[0].price
trackerResult.orders[1].items[0].productId
trackerResult.orders[1].items[0].productName
```

To put this info onto an HTML page you need to do something like:

```
document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = trackerResult.orders[1].items[0].price;
document.getElementById('productId').innerHTML = trackerResult.orders[1].items[0].productId;
document.getElementById('productName').innerHTML = trackerResult.orders[1].items[0].productName;
```

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tNmRW/1/

Answer (score 0):

> but as I understand what I am looking at there is properties that are technically a child of a child?

Yup! You've also got a property that's an array in there.

To access a property in an object simply write the following code:

```
alert(trackerResult.sessionId);
```

This is a value type property. Numbers are another example of a value type.

To access a property of a child object just follow the same logic:

```
alert(trackerResult.contact.firstName);
```

It's not much different than the first example. You're accessing a property which is a type that contains it's own properties. You can tell this because of the braces `{}`.

The last example is an array type. Accessing these is a little bit different. First you need to determine the size of the array. You can do this by accessing the length property available for all arrays.

```
alert("There are " + trackerResult.orders.length + " order(s)!");
```

Once you have the length of an array you can use a for loop to iterate through them like so:

```
for(var x = 0; x < trackerResult.orders.length; x++)
    alert("Order number " + trackerResult.orders[x].number + " has " + trackerResult.orders[x].items.length + " items!");
```

From there you can create another loop to iterate through the items of each order.