# Declare object that can be assigned in this manner

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

Suppose I want to have a javascript object that can be assigned using somewhat similar syntax below;

```
parent.child1.property1 = "xx"
parent.child1.property2 = "xx"
parent.child1.property3 = "yy"

parent.child2.property1 = "xx"
parent.child2.property2 = "xx"
parent.child2.property3 = "yy"
```

If this can be done, how should such a object be declared?

Comment: Strictly, you declare variables, not objects. The variable declaration can include an assignment of a value, which might be defined using an *object literal* or *object initialiser*. See aggaton's answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Aggaton's example would work, however you would need to call the index since square brackets creates an array.</strike> He has since updated his answer.

If you want to use dot notation like you specified in the original just setup the data as nested objects as such:

```
var parent = {

 child1: {
  property1: "one",
  property2: "two",
  property3: "three"
 },

 child2: {
  property1: "one",
  property2: "two",
  property3: "three"
 }
};

console.log(parent.child1.property1); // "one"
console.log(parent.child2.property2); // "two"
```

Also a somewhat similar answer that shows you good notation: [Nested JSON objects - do I have to use arrays for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098276/nested-json-objects-do-i-have-to-use-arrays-for-everything)

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. After the object has been declared, can new children like `child3` and `child4` be added dynamically? Or does one need to create a new object?

Comment: You can add new objects to the parent object using a similar dot notation that you use to access the object you are after.

`var parent = {};` // Create empty object
`parent.child = 1;` // Create and assign a child object of value = 1
`console.log(parent.child);` // Returns 1

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe

```
var parent = 
{child1: {property1:"xx",property2:"xx",property3:"yy"},
 child2: {property1:"xx",property2:"xx",property3:"yy"}};
```