# Decoding and looping through PHP JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I have the following deocoded JSON array.
I need to access the "type" inside the context, as well as I need to loop through each of the values in the payload. How do I do that?

```
 {
   "RequestHeader":  
      {  
                  "mess": "am putting it on my wall....",
                  "created_time": "2010-08-24T09:01:25+0000"  
                  },
    "context" : 

                       {
                           "type": "friends,circles"

                        }

   "payload" [ {12345},{12345} ,{2345}  ]

   }
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work

```
$decoded = json_decode($json_string);

for ($i=0;$i<payload.length;++$i)

{

$id=$decoded->payload[$i];
//do some operation with the id

}
```

Comment: Enable error reporting. That's not PHP.

Comment: That's not valid JSON

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12970107/6213452) may be helpful before proceed to server script.

Comment: what you are doing `payload.length` what it is? it is not a php variable. Wake up it is php not javascript.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the JSON you provided is invalid. Supposedly the valid one should look like this

```
 {
    "RequestHeader": {
        "mess": "am putting it on my wall....",
        "created_time": "2010-08-24T09:01:25+0000"
    },
    "context": {
        "type": "friends,circles"
    },
    "payload": [
        12345,
        12345,
        2345
    ]
 }
```

After you've fixed the problem with JSON provider it will be quite easy to access data

```
<?php

$json = <<<'JSON'
{
    "RequestHeader": {
        "mess": "am putting it on my wall....",
        "created_time": "2010-08-24T09:01:25+0000"
    },
    "context": {
        "type": "friends,circles"
    },
    "payload": [
        12345,
        12345,
        2345
    ]
}
JSON;

$data = json_decode($json, true);

$type = $data['context']['type'];
var_dump($type);
foreach($data['payload'] as $id) {
    var_dump($id);
}
```

Remember to make sure you check that the data actually exists before accessing it, e.g. `isset($data['context']['type'])` unless you are absolutely sure in it's integrity.

Answer (score -1):

When you use json_decode method, the output will be nested arrays
So for example to access context type you need to do the following

```
echo $decoded["context"]["type"];
```

And to loop on payload you need to do the following

```
for ($i=0;$i<$decoded["payload"].length;++$i)
{

$id=$decoded["payload"][$i];
//do some operation with the id

}
```

Comment: Not sure how you ended up with an upvote, but this is wrong on several levels.